# Resizable jQuery function remembers width with cookie but applies to all cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, session-cookies

I have created a function to remember the resize width and height of my table cell. The jquery applies this resize to all cells upon my return to the page. How would I go about only applying that to the td that was initially resized?

[DEMO - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q1pke43h/)

You will see in the demo, if you resize a cell and reload, the width and height would be applied to all cells.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof($.cookie('height')!='undefined'))
    {
        $("td").height($.cookie("height"));
        $("td").width($.cookie("width"));
    }
    $( "td" ).resizable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var width = ui.size.width;
            var height = ui.size.height;
            $.cookie("height",height);
            $.cookie("width",width);
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an answer in this jsFiddle.
[JSFIDDLE - EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thusitha92/tvp6poce/1/)

You need to have two additional `cookies` to remember `row` and `column` count of the last resized `cell`. When page loads we get the `cell` by `[row, col]` and apply the `width` and `height`.

Here I applied `width` for the `column` and `height` for the row. Keep in mind that if you change the row `height` of one `cell` the whole row height will increase. *That's the intended table behaviour*.

This will only remember the last cell properties.
If you want to remember all the cell properties one by one, you need to use
another mechanism like `localstorage` with a support of an array.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the JSfiddle is the same as the original?

Comment: @TomRudge Check now

Comment: That's really cool, cheers, changing another cell overrides the previous cookies width and height

Comment: That's why I mentioned in the answer that you need to have a cell array to keep all the width and height values. You can use localstorage to do that.